# python gspread - How to delete/remove column in google-sheet-API

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, gspread

I'm logging data from a CSV file to google sheet using gspread in python with values_update().

I then use gspread-formatting to create a background color. Since I haven’t found a way to format colors from the CSV, my script reads the data in column C where I store the color I want to use.

After creating the background color I want to delete column C including the header (row 1)

What is the best way to delete or remove an entire column?
Alternatively, if there is a way to log the background color straight from the CSV file that will be even better.

```
projectSheet.values_update(
worksheet, params={'valueInputOption': 'USER_ENTERED'},
body={'values': list(csv.reader(open(csvName)))}
)

blue = [cell.row for cell in worksheet.findall('Blue')]
for i in blue:
    fmtBlue = cellFormat(
    backgroundColor=color(0.5, 0.5, 1),
    textFormat=textFormat(bold=False, foregroundColor=color(0, 0, 0)),
    horizontalAlignment='CENTER'
    )
    rows = f'A{i}:J{i}'
    format_cell_range(worksheet, rows, fmtBlue)

worksheet.delete_column('C')???
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to delete the columns using gspread.
- You have already been able to put and get values using Sheets API.
- Your question is as follows.

  - What is the best way to delete or remove an entire column?
  - If there is a way to log the background color straight from the CSV file that will be even better.

If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script? Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `If there is a way to log the background color straight from the CSV file.`. So I cannot answer it. But I can answer about `What is the best way to delete or remove an entire column?`. So here, I would like to propose the method for deleting the columns using gspread.

It seems that there is no method of `delete_column` in gspread. So in this case, I would like to propose to use `batch_update()` of gspread. Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Sample script:

```
spreadsheetId = "###"  # Please set Spreadsheet ID.
sheetName = "###"  # Please set sheet name which has the columns you want to delete.

spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)
sheetId = spreadsheet.worksheet(sheetName)._properties['sheetId']
body = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "deleteDimension": {
                "range": {
                    "sheetId": sheetId,
                    "dimension": "COLUMNS",
                    "startIndex": 2,
                    "endIndex": 3
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
res = spreadsheet.batch_update(body)
print(res)
```

- Please set the range as the GridRange.
- In above script, the column "C" is deleted.

#### References:

- [batch_update(body)](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.batch_update)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [DeleteDimensionRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#deletedimensionrequest)
- [GridRange](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#GridRange)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.